# Overleaf repeating sections in altacv

Tags: overleaf

I'm using [this](https://sv.overleaf.com/articles/ronak-dedhiyas-cv/dhvyjtfwwkzg) template to make a CV but when I add content to `page1sidebar.tex` it repeats the `\cvsection`'s I add there.

I've tried to replace what I have with the template's content for the `page1sidebar.tex` but it still repeats. I've also double checked the end of `mmayer.tex` as maybe I could've left something unclosed but it ends just as the template.

What could be creating this repetition?

EDIT: Added

```
\cvsection[page1sidebar]{Experience}

\cvevent{Job}{Company}{Nov 2018 -- Present}{}
\begin{itemize}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{itemize}

\clearpage
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

to the end of the `mmayer.tex` and it seems to be what makes the sections on `page1sidebar.tex` repeat but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

The optional parameter you're passing in

```
\cvsection[page1sidebar]{Experience}
```

tells it to use the `page1sidebar`, but the experience section is on a new page so it is repeating the sidebar. If you don't want it to have a sidebar then remove the option:

```
\cvsection{Experience}
```

Or if you want the sidebar to have different content then change it to

```
\cvsection[page2sidebar]{Experience}
```

and add additional content to `page2sidebar.tex`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably placing a `[page1sidebar]` for each `\cvsection`. When doing this, the latex places a `page1sidebar.tex` attached to each `\cvsection` with `[page1sidebar]`, causing repetition. What you have to do is place `[page1sidebar]` in just one `\cvsection` that you want to associate. It is usually the first `\cvsection`.